# Term or Stat for when a baseball pitcher is responsible for the team's win, both offensively and defensively?

Tags: baseball, terminology, mlb, pitching

> Is there a term or a recorded statistic for when a baseball pitcher is
>   responsible for winning the game both defensively and offensively?

i.e...
1. The pitcher batted and had an RBI/Run, which was either the only run scored or the winning/last run scored

2. They pitched well enough to keep the opposing team's score lower than their own (producing a win)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPA (Win Probability Added) does what you are looking for, although with some limitations. WPA takes the difference in win expectancy for each team for each play and assigns it to the pitcher (for the defense) and the batter (for the offense). Since both pitching and hitting components are measured, a pitcher's contributions both on the mound and at the plate can be considered. I'm not aware of any site that actually combines those two numbers, but it's easy enough to just add it up.

The highest offensive WPA contribution for a pitcher of 2015 was Steven Matz's game on [June 28 against the Reds](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/NYN/NYN201506280.shtml) (according to Baseball Reference Play Index). He went 3-for-3 (2 singles and a double) driving in four, which added up to 41% WPA. He also pitched 7.2 innings giving up two runs, which accounts for another 12% WPA. So total, he contributed 53% WPA to the Mets that game. Not bad for a Major League debut.

A couple of things to keep in mind about WPA. On the defense side, all of the value is attributed to the pitcher. So if a fielder makes a great play, the pitcher gets all of the credit. Also, it's all about context, so closers tend to have really high WPA values because they come into games that could go either way (~50% win expectancy), and if they close out the victory (100% win expectancy), the WPA will be ~50%. In a blowout, it's difficult to gain (or lose) WPA because the outcome of the game is largely determined already.

See Fangraphs for a [good summary of WPA](http://www.fangraphs.com/library/misc/wpa/).

Answer (score 2):

"Player of the Game" (joking). There is no **ACTUAL** stat for what you are asking, it is just a great game played by the pitcher. The pitcher can get offensive stats for "walk offs", and they can get defensive stats such as a "win" towards their pitching stats. But there is not a stat that combines the pitcher's offensive and defensive performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an expression for this - though as mentioned, no stat.  The expression that is most commonly used is (and this is definitely an artful expression rather than a statistical one)  is "helping themselves".   Another common way this is referred to is "doing it all".

Those are both normal phrases, and probably wouldn't be worth mentioning if not for the fact that their use is ubiquitous enough to give them some sort of standardization.

Incidentally there is also something called "the shut 'em out / home run club" ( a highly exclusive club ) for pitchers who have homered while pitching a complete game shutout. Kershaw is the most recent. See the [list](http://www.truebluela.com/2013/4/2/4172718/clayton-kershaw-dodgers-home-run-shutout).